# Identify source of a SQL Server job running nightly

Tags: sql-server

I am looking into performance issues with an app that uses SQL Server Express (Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP2) (KB3171021) - 12.0.5000.0 (X64)) for the back end database.

I'm logging slow running queries using Extended Events. Looking at these I have identified a job that runs every night a series of queries, some of which take quite an extended period. The longest single query takes 10 minutes or so. It seems to be some sort of reporting, gathering broad information about everything in the tables it is looking at.

This seems to be an automated process that is running nightly at exactly the same time and takes about the same length of time to execute each night (around 20 minutes).

It runs on a Windows account with Administrative privileges that connects to SQL using Windows authentication. There is other legit stuff we do know about also running on this account.

The client doesn't know what it is.

The app name logged is just ".Net SqlClient Data Provider" which I believe is a generic default.

This is different than the client application which identifies itself correctly. I have identified with the client everything else that is running against the database- there are a few other jobs that generate accounting emails for example.

I can't find anything in Windows Scheduled Tasks that corresponds and SQL Express obviously doesn't have SQL Server Agent- everything other SQL job I have identified is scheduled in Windows Scheduled Tasks.

I've tried turning login auditing on and I can see the login occurring but it gives even less information as to what it is, it doesn't even give me the client app name.

I have no reason to believe it is in any way malicious, it is likely something that was set up years ago and simply forgotten.

Any ideas for how I could pinpoint where exactly this is coming from?

Comment: If it calls a stored proc or does an insert you could modify that stored proc to dump many of the identifying @@ variables and locate the source.  Since it looks like .NET you could probably decompile the code and figure it out.

Comment: It doesn't seem to, it's all SELECT statements from what I can see.

Comment: Do a sql trace and capture everything around midnight when it runs.  You should get the details that will let you figure out what exe is actually calling the code.  You do nto need the trace all the time - just a little before until just after it runs.  practice on some other running processes to make sure you are getting all the trace fields that are process and machine identifying in nature.

Comment: I'm already getting this out of Extended Events which have replaced traces. SQL Server Express doesn't have SQL Profiler either, but AFAIK you can get everything through EE that you used be able to get through traces.

The issue I have is there isn't anything obvious captured by SQL Server that would actually let me pinpoint what is doing this. All I have is the "client_app_name" field which is ".Net SqlClient Data Provider" which doesn't really help. Other options I can capture include client_connection_id and client_pid (process ID) but I am not sure how these might help me ID the app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to do this while you think the mystery program is running.
Open a Remote Desktop windows session on the actual SQL server since you are pretty sure that is where it is running.
Have TaskMgr.exe ready.  Go to the “Details” tab so that you can search by TaskManager PID (not SQL PID) .    Sort by this TaskMgr PID.
Right Click on the Columns at the top of this Details tab..  Choose “Select Columns” 
Add this column …
    Command line

While you think the mystery program is running run the following sql.

```
select x.host_process_id as USE_ME_TaskMgr_PID_OnClient_PC       
     , x.host_name as PCNameFromClient 
     , x.program_name as ProgNmFromClient   
     , x.client_interface_name
     , x.original_login_name 
     , x.login_name 
     , x.nt_domain 
     , x.nt_user_name
     , x.* 
   FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions x 
   order by x.host_name DESC 
          , x.program_name DESC          
   GO
```

Look at the first column of this sql.  Find your mystery program in the list.  Take the first value. This is the Program PID that will be the PID on the TaskMgr PID.  Then you will see the command line full execution directory path.

Comment: Many thanks. I am not following this exactly as it is middle of the night when I am asleep but this has put me on the right track. In Extended Events I am logging **client_pid** which from checking in Task Manager as you suggest I can confirm is the Windows PID. To record a history of process PIDs I have turned on **Audit process tracking** in Group Policy. This then logs all new process creations. I can then view this in the Windows Event Viewer in the Security Log and correlate **NewProcessId** (hex) with the (decimal) client_pid from the SQL EE log. **NewProcessName** gives me the full path

Comment: Just to confirm- doing the above I was able to identify the mystery program from the logs this morning. Many thanks Sql Surfer.

Answer (score 0):

By using something like sp_who you can find the hostname for each user connecting. Maybe that can give you a hint on where to look?

Comment: I have the hostname already from the Extended Events, whatever it is is running on the same machine the database server is on. Ideally what I would like to find out is the path to the executable doing it.